# Trimming fgets(): strlen() or strtok()

Tags: c, strings, io, comparative-review

After a successful `fgets(buffer, ...)`, it is often desirable to trim a potential End-of-Line `'\n'`.

Of the following 2 methods, are there any shortcomings?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char buffer[100];

// Method 1
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {
  size_t len = strlen(buffer);
  if (len > 0 && buffer[len - 1] == '\n')
    buffer[--len] = '\0';

  // use buffer
  printf("\"%s\"\n", buffer);
}

// Method 2
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {
  strtok(buffer, "\n");

  // use buffer
  printf("\"%s\"\n", buffer);
}
```

Notes:

1. When reading text files from alternate file systems, `strtok(buffer, "\r\n")` looks useful.
2. `strtok()` may incur an issue with another `strtok()` sequence.

Comment: Could you please make this into a short runnable program with examples of how you have tested it and expect it to run?  And could you expand what you mean by "incur an issue with another `strtok()` sequence"?

Comment: @syb0rg `strtok()` is not re-entrant. There is a `strtok_r()` variant that is re-entrant.

Comment: @200_success I know, I thought that is what he meant but just wanted to confirm. Note that `strtok_r` is provided by the POSIX standard, and that `strtok_s` is the C11 standard version.

Comment: @syb0rg 1) In re: "incur an issue with another `strtok()` sequence": If code was in the middle of calling a series of `strtok()` to perform some other tokenizing, then this use of `strtok()` would fouls things up.  That does not seem  likely, but is a down side.  2) Thanks 1K 3) Did not know about `strtok_r()` 4) `strtok_s()` in in the normative "Bounds-checking interfaces" section of C11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it is worth, using `strlen` is much more efficient than using `strtok`.  I did some tests (omitting the file access) using `strlen`, `strchr`, `strtok`, `strstr`, `strpbrk` and `strcspn`:

It surprised me that to execute this neat looking thing:

```
s = strchr(s, '\n');
if (s) {
    *s = '\0';
}
```

takes nearly 50% longer than this ugly looking sucker:

```
size_t len = strlen(s);
if (len && (s[len-1] == '\n')) {
    s[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

and the beautiful

```
strtok(s, "\n\r");
```

and

```
strsep(&s, "\n\r");
```

are 10 to 20 times slower.  The latter two do of course look for \r as well as \n. But even adding \r, the `strlen` approach is still quicker than the `strchr` and still quicker then `strtok` and `strsep` by 10 to 20 times:

```
size_t len = strlen(s);
if (len && ((s[len-1] == '\n') || (s[len-1] == '\r'))) {
    s[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

Note that I wasn't exhaustive with string variations.  In fact I didn't even break a sweat.  And of course this is all quite irrelevant as the `stdio` call will dominate in your target code :-)

Note also from the comments below that if the first character of the search string (`s` in the examples above) is one of the characters in the pattern string, `strtok` does nothing (thanks to @chux).

Comment: Recently found out `strtok(s, "\n\r");` does not always trim the `'\n'` from `s`.  When `s == "\n"`.  The `'\n'` remains.

Comment: @chux  I tried it on a Mac and you are right - which system did you use? I'm shocked - it is rather like finding out that an old friend has a dark secret. And it is not specific to `\n` - if any char in the search pattern appears as the first char in `s`, `strtok` does nothing. My man page doesn't describe this behaviour. Another reason not to use `strtok` - `strsep` works as expected.

Comment: Might want to add this about `strtok()` as relates to "are there any shortcomings?"  Looked into `char *ptr = buffer; strsep(ptr, "\n")` and did not find any functional shortcomings, other than it is non-standard.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the `scanf()` functionality do the work for you.

```
char buffer[100];

int  len;
if (fscanf(stdin, "%99[^\n]%n", buffer, &len) != 1)
{
     // No data (or just a '\n')
     len = 0;
}
fscanf(stdin, "%*[^\n]"); /* If the line is longer than 99 this throws away
                           * The rest of the line upto the new line character
                           */
buffer[len] = '\0';
fscanf(stdin, "%*c");     /* read and throw away the newline 
                           */
```

Comment: Interesting idea this different approach.  Forming the needed width of `"99"` is not much an issue when the buffer size is well know (as in my example), but forming the width when the size is not a literal constant need more code.  Doable, but cumbersome.

Comment: @chux: Not really that cumbersome if you wrap it in a function.

Comment: Could use `int len = 0; fscanf(stdin, "%99[^\n]%n", buffer, &len);` and skip the `if()` test for same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, I tried a few alternative ways of doing the file access.  I tried your `fgets` and the suggested alternatives from other answers.

On my system, using `fgets`, which you used, is about the same speed as using `getline`. Using `fscanf` is about 3x slower than these solutions.  The fastest method I tested was to use `fgetln` (available on a Mac from the BSD C library), which was 10-15% faster than `fgets`/`getline`.

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

while ((line = fgetln(f, &len)) != NULL) {
    if (line[len - 1] == '\n') {
        line[len - 1] = '\0';
    }
    //printf("\"%s\"\n", line);
}
if (ferror(f)) {
    perror("fgetln");
}
```

Another alternative is to use `mmap` to map the file (only real files though, not pipes, etc) into memory and use string handling directly (`strchr` etc) to look for line endings.  This might be the fastest of all but I didn't test it here.

Generally it is best not to get too hung up about speed unless you know that a piece of code is critical (and normally one doesn't know this). So think more about the advantages and disadvantages of the various solutions:

- `fgets` is quick but uses a fixed buffer length and you have to handle overflow as a special case.
- `getline` and `fgetln` are quick, elegant and capture complete lines.  These are attractive if we do not need to worry about attacks by huge strings.  `fgetln` is not in any standard so is rather less portable than `getline` (which seems to be POSIX). I tried `fgetln` with a file containing one line > INT_MAX chars long (INT_MAX is the limit that `fgetln` handles) and although it did slow down the system considerably, it failed cleanly with a memory allocation failure:

  ```
  fgetln: Cannot allocate memory
  ```

  `getline` has a limit of SSIZE_MAX which is much bigger.
- `fscanf` - I can't think of a reason to use this for the simple example you pose, but it has its uses if you want to control the input format.
- `mmap` is (probably) quick and elegant but only handles real files, which restricts the application a bit (eg you can't just pipe input into the application if it wants to map a file).

Comment: Oops, you are right. My man page says it is in the Standard C Library (libc, -lc), but I guess that does not mean it is in the C standard as the history section says only "The fgetln() function first appeared in 4.4BSD.". I'll edit the answer...

Answer (score 3):

It seems silly to have to call `strlen()` or `strtok()` to find the end-of-line delimiter, when surely the system could have already known how many bytes were successfully read into `buffer`.

Also consider how you want to handle the case where the input line is too long for the buffer.

To take care of both issues, I suggest using `getline()` instead:

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t buflen = 0;
ssize_t len;

while ((len = getline(&line, &buflen, stdin)) > 0) {
    if (line[len - 1] == '\n') {
        line[--len] = '\0';
    }

    // use buffer
    printf("\"%s\"\n", line);
}
```

Comment: I look forward to using `getline()` more with its allocated buffer once it becomes part of the C standard.  Of course one could roll their own `getline()` in the mean time.  A niche area concern that I have with `getline()` is the inability to limit the line length.  A limit is useful to prevent hostile input from creating some huge input aimed to overwhelm code resources.

Comment: How _would_ you want the program to behave in the face of unreasonably long input lines? Your two original methods avoid exhaustion, but they don't feel quite correct either.

Comment: Various approaches: 1) consume input up to a point and toss the rest, then report the error. (prevents OOM) 2) consume and process input up to a limit, recognize it as an attack and report the error (prevent OOM and spinning the CPU)